# upgrade existing server to use Hyper V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-sbs-2008

We have a small office with one server on SBS 2008 and we don't have a budget right now to buy a new server.

Is it possible to buy a new harddrive, install hyper V then install the latest SBS 2012 and then move over all the data to the new server?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just back up your data, upgrade the OS and restore your data?

Comment: @John SBS cannot be upgraded, only migrated.

Comment: @Mark, that's the new thing I learned today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)  to make an image of your current OS. Put your original hdd aside in case you need it.

Install Hyper-V and import your vhd.

Then, install 2012 in a new VM and run the migration tools. Then, shut down the old VM.

Comment: Hi Mark, this sounds like a workable solution. What about moving Exchange data from the old server to the new? --edit, sorry just noticed you were referring to migration tools. Do they include reliable tools for Exchange migration?

Comment: @Jacques - yes. The instructions that come with 2012 are very good, I've done the migration three times now and it's gone without issue every time. Two 2008 -> 2012 and one 2003 -> 2012.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I must admit, I'm very nervous about this. Any recommended steps to follow to avoid loss of data or services when it's all done?

Comment: I'm assuming that the end result should be that I have SBS 2008 running along side the new SBS 2011. Question is... Will they work like that? No conflicts in Active Directory? Or should the new SBS 2011 be setup to run with a different Directory name?

Comment: @Jacques - You really must read the SBS 2011 migration document. It explains everything really well. You do not actually install SBS 2011 normally, you create a migration answer file from 2008, and then it automates the 2011 installation for you. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490796.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll start reading. I just realised yesterday that it seems SBS 2012 is coming soon, so I'm thinking we might wait a while. So this gives me time to prepare.